# May a standards-compliant C assert() evaluate its argument multiple times?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, language-lawyer, assert

Is the standard C `assert(e)` macro permitted to evaluate `e` multiple times?  What about C++11 or later?  I don't see any guarantees in [the Open Group spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/assert.html), and the answer isn't apparent to me from some searching ([1](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/~johnr/tutorials/assertions.html), [2](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_34.html)).

Context: could `func()` be called multiple times in `assert(func() != NULL)`?

Yes, I already know this is a bad idea for other reasons: as [the glibc manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_34.html) points out, the argument of `assert()` won't be evaluated at all if `NDEBUG` is defined.  However, assuming `NDEBUG` is *not* defined, is there any guarantee on the *maximum* number of times `e` is evaluated?

<sup>Question prompted by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39664376/2877364).</sup>

Comment: two questions: Does it matter? Why would any implementation do so?

Comment: I don' think C specifies how often the expression is evaluated.

Comment: As far as I can determine, C does not specify whether the expression may be evaluated more than once.  However, I don't see why any plausible implementation would evaluate it multiple times.

Comment: @tobi303 It may not matter, but I'm curious :) .  Maybe you could use this for code that should *only* be run in debug mode - it's more concise than an `#ifdef`/`#endif` block.  Perhaps `func()` would evaluate some complex precondition or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The C standard says

In the C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011), §7.1.4 **Use of library functions** says:

> Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: …
>
> Any invocation of a library function that is implemented as a macro shall expand to code that evaluates each of its arguments exactly once, fully protected by parentheses where necessary, so it is generally safe to use arbitrary expressions as arguments.<sup>186)</sup> Likewise, those function-like macros described in the following subclauses may be invoked in an expression anywhere a function with a compatible return type could be called.<sup>187)</sup>
>
> <sup>186)</sup> Such macros might not contain the sequence points that the corresponding function calls do.
>
> <sup>187)</sup> Because external identifiers and some macro names beginning with an underscore are reserved, implementations may provide special semantics for such names. For example, the identifier `_BUILTIN_abs` could be used to indicate generation of in-line code for the `abs` function. Thus, the appropriate header could specify
>
> ```
> #define abs(x) _BUILTIN_abs(x)
> ```
>
> for a compiler whose code generator will accept it. In this manner, a user desiring to guarantee that a given library function such as `abs` will be a genuine function may write
>
> ```
> #undef abs
> ```
>
> whether the implementation’s header provides a macro implementation of `abs` or a built-in implementation. The prototype for the function, which precedes and is hidden by any macro definition, is thereby revealed also.

The preamble in §7.2 **Diagnostics `<assert.h>`** says:

> The `assert` macro shall be implemented as a macro, not as an actual function. If the macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual function, the behavior is undefined.

And section §7.2.1.1 **The `assert` macro** says:

> The `assert` macro puts diagnostic tests into programs; it expands to a void expression. When it is executed, if `expression` (which shall have a scalar type) is false (that is, compares equal to 0), the `assert` macro writes information about the particular call that failed (including the text of the argument, the name of the source file, the source line
>   number, and the name of the enclosing function — the latter are respectively the values of the preprocessing macros `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` and of the identifier `__func__`) on the standard error stream in an implementation-defined format.<sup>191)</sup> It then calls the `abort` function.
>
> <sup>191)</sup> The message written might be of the form:
>   `Assertion failed:`*`expression`*`, function`*`abc`*`, file`*`xyz`*`, line`*`nnn`*`.`

#### A possible interpretation of the standard

So much for the verbiage of the standard — how does that translate in practice?

A lot hinges on the interpretation of the statement:

- *Any invocation of a library function that is implemented as a macro shall expand to code that evaluates each of its arguments exactly once*

If `assert` is regarded as a function that is implemented via a macro, then its argument shall be evaluated just once (the conversion to string is a compile-time operation that does not evaluate the expression).

If `assert` is regarded as 'not a function' (because it is explicitly a macro), then the restriction quoted doesn't necessarily apply to it.

In practice, I'm sure that the intent is that the expression argument to `assert` should only be evaluated once (and that only if `NDEBUG` was not defined when the `<assert.h>` header was last included) — so I'd regard it as being constrained as if it was a function that is implemented via a macro.  I'd also regard any implementation that implemented `assert` in such a way that the expression was evaluated twice as defective.  I'm not certain that the quoted material supports that, but it is all the relevant material I know of in the standard.

Comment: I would definitely argue that `assert` is explicitly a macro, not a library function implemented as a macro.  But I also doubt the standard authors intended `#define assert(x) __assert_impl(((x), (x)), #x)` to be a valid implementation.